# Python - criando tabela

Tags: python, tabela-html

tenho duas variáveis (coordenadas X,Y) que estou retirando estas informações de uma tabela .plt, gostaria de salvá-las em uma outra tabela.
gostaria que a tabela ficasse assim

```
   X   Y
  10   48
  10   50
  20   30
```

sou novo em python, conseguiria acessar essa tabela para leitura depois indicando a variável ( X ou Y ) e a linha para visualizar esta variável?
esta tabela teria que ter um tamanho variável, porque o tamanho dela vai depender do arquivo eu vou carregar

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar uma tuple do python para fazer isso.

```
##Primeira X, segunda Y
tabela = [ (10,48 ), ( 10,50 ), (20, 30 ) ]
```

`tabela[0]` retornaria (10,48)
Se você quiser acessar o X, você so precisa acessar o primeiro item: `tabela[0][0]`

Exite tambem uma forma de você criar a tabela de forma que cada elemento

```
>>> tabela = [ (10,48 ), ( 10,50 ), (20, 30 ) ]
>>> tabela[0][0]
10
```

Comment: obrigado por sua resposta, mas consigo salvar estas variáveis em qualquer lugar da tabela ?

Comment: Desculpa, Não entendi sua pergunta. Você diz exportar a informação?

Answer (score 0):

Tabelas podem ser representadas utilizando diferentes tipos de Estrutura de Dados.
A mais simples seria criar uma matriz usando arrays:

```
table = [ [10,48] , [10,50] , [20,30] ]
```

Você pode acessar os dados usando o index como:

```
''' Acessar cada linha '''
>>> table[0]
[10,48]
''' Ou acessar diretamento o valor por coluna: '''
>>> table[0][1]
48
```

Mas caso queira armazenar esses dados externamente, seria interessante utilizar o [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) para converter para CSV, Excel, etc.